# Getting information about payment woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a question regarding Woocommerce: we sell tickets on our website and would like to generate a list of users that bought a ticket, together with whether they have paid or not. It should look like this:

username/nickname    paid/not paid

Is it possible to do that with Woocommerce? If so, could you enlighten me with a possible code? :)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Woocommerce has an orders menu option and it will show you the orders that have been placed and the status of them (paid/unpaid). In your case it would show the tickets instead.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. That's handy for the backend, but I would like to automatically show those things on the frontend too, like on a page. I'm sorry if this wasn't clear from my original question...